# Selenium Run Functional Tests Distribute By Test Time

Tags: selenium, testing, tfs, automation, automated-tests

I'm running Run Functional Tests distributed by machines number.

Now I've around 850 tests and it takes around 3.5 hours. (8 Servers)

I added another 8 servers and now it takes around 2.2 hours.

Because it distributed by machine number, every machine gets 53 tests but there are tests which takes 30 seconds and some tests that takes 5 mintues.

That situation is annoying, because there are machine which finish after their job after (53 * 30seconds) = 1500 seconds, around 25 minutes while there are servers which finish their work after 2 hours.

It makes my build very slower.

I want somehow to distribute it by running time, so that every machine will work the same time and start and finish at the same time.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task `Run functional tests` is deprecated in VSTS and TFS 2018. Instead of using `Run functional tests`, you should use [Visual Studio Test](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTestV2/README.md) task.

[image]

Task `Visual Studio Test` in VSTS/TFS 2018, supports `Based on past running time of tests`. **Based on past running time of tests**: This batching considers past running time to create batches of tests such that each batch has approximately equal running time. This option should meet you requirement.

[image]